# Compare a character to a character code?

Tags: conditionals, characters, comparison

How can one compare a character (e.g. "U") with a character code in a certain font (e.g. "\char85").

I'd expect the following to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\font\X=cmr10
\X
U looks like \char85, ...%
\if U \char85 { and U is \char85 } \else { but U is not \char85 } \fi

% Or using the `ifthen` package:    
Plus, 
\ifthenelse{\equal{U}{\char85}}{ then U is U too }{ then U is not U, too }
\end{document}
```

Alas, neither works as expected.

Thoughts and input are appreciated.

### Edit

It is helpful to note that:

```
\meaning \char 85 \\
\meaning \char'U  \\
\meaning U
```

Produces the output:

```
“char85
"char'U
the letter U
```

These are clearly different internally, and I presume must be normalized before comparison.

Comment: In the first two cases, the `\meaning` is just showing the meaning of `\char`. This is more obvious if you use `\show`. You can see that it hasn't looked at the 85 or `'U` (Presumably, you mean <code>`U</code> anyway.)

Comment: @TH.: `<code>` doesn't work in comments. In this case, `\``U\`` would have done it `:-)`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to determine? That is, when is this test *not* going to return true? When you type ``U`, you'll always get `85` as the interpreted number. You can't ask the font for which character is at a certain slot; it just doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Hendrik: I guess I knew it wouldn't work, but I couldn't be bothered trying to figure out how to get the markdown to work. I wish comments were consistent with answers and questions. (Just testing. ``U`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a notion of a character code in a font. I think what you're looking for is

```
\ifnum`U=85 ...\else ...\fi
```

Note that since `U` has ASCII value 85, `U` and `\char85` are both going to give you character in position 85 of the current font.

Answer (score 4):

do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\chardef\tempA=`U

\font\X=cmr10
\X
U looks like \char85, ...%
\chardef\tempB=085
\ifx\tempA\tempB and U is \char85 \else but U is not \char85 \fi

\end{document}
```